# Android Studio,After setting up shows :gradle project sync failed.Basic functionally will not work properly

Tags: android

Error:Unable to start the daemon process: could not reserve enough space for object heap.
Please assign more memory to Gradle in the project's gradle.properties file.
For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:
*org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m*
[Read Gradle's configuration guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html)
[Read about Java's heap size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html)

However if I really changed org.gradle.jvmargs to 1024，then the computer will be jamed and i can't do anything except restart my computer.my computer is a 32-bit computer,what should i do?

Comment: I think sadly you need a better computer to do Java development on - the IDE alone uses quite a bit of RAM, not counting when it's building.